Docker Compose Project Name is Wrong
I have a problem with docker compose, if I don't define the project name in the docker compose up -d command, the project name will use the current active folder, or in this case "opc"
but after I run it, I actually get the name "rengine" which is a different folder
Docker Compose
How i can fix this problem?
Environment:
OS : Oracle Linux 8
arch : arm64
Docker : 27.4.0

#Update 11 December 2024
i found the problem
on my folder, there is a .env file from another project, inside this file in the file there is COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=rengine
by default, when there is an .env, docker will take variable data from the file.
